# mpdf shows failed to load pdf document in all browsers

Tags: codeigniter-3, mpdf

I used MPDF in Codeigniter when I view the pdf page it load few seconds and shows Failed to load pdf and this error was reflect in all browsers.In othercase, I used DOMPDF to automatically download the pdf, after downloading that pdf I opened in Adobe Reader and it shows [image]

Now, what can I do?Pls help to solve this issue.

This is my View pdf.php:

```
<?php foreach ($datas as $data){} ?>
<?php foreach($company as $cmp){} ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php
echo '<table class="table table-hover" align="center" style="border:1px solid 
black;border-collapse:collpase;font-family:Roboto;font-size:15px">
<tbody>';
echo '<tr style="border-bottom:hidden"><td colspan="5" style="font- 
weight:bold">'.$cmp->company_name.'</td><td align="right" style="font- 
weight:bold">Quote NO.:</td><td>'.$data->quote_id.'</td></tr></tbody> 
</table>';?>
```

Controller:

```
public function quote_generate_pdf($id)
{
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

// load library
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();

// retrieve data from model
$result=$this->customer_model->customer_quotation_view($id);
$company=$this->customer_model->our_details();
if($result!=false)
{
$data['datas']=$result;
$data['company']=$company;
}
else {
$data['datas']='NA';
}

// boost the memory limit if it's low ;)
$html = $this->load>view('pdf',$data,true);//test
// render the view into HTML
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);

// write the HTML into the PDF
$output = 'itemreport' . date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '_.pdf';
$pdf->Output("$output", 'I');
}
```

This is library Pdf.php

```
<?php
class pdf {

function load($param=NULL)
{
include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
if ($params == NULL)
{
$param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';
}
return new mPDF($param);
//return new mPDF();
}
}?>
```

Comment: I think you should show some code on how you're using mPDF to convert text/html to PDF.

Comment: See https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/corrupt-pdf-file.html